# Javascript: What is a nice curry example?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that if you apply this code:

```
var curry = function(x) {
    return function(y) {
        return x + y;
    };
};

console.log(curry(3)(2));
```

You could apply the sum of 3+2, this is what is called "Curry", but I don't find it very useful, I would like to know, if there are many others good examples and cases to use it

Comment: Real world example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/185585/22659 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5301181/218196

Comment: @Germanaz0 Here is an example of how I use this pattern sometimes with map: http://jsfiddle.net/bcj9q8c2/

Comment: Thanks @dfsq for repliying, the example is very cool